# div not obeying height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an element with a div in it, the div is a slightly smaller box then the outer, and makes it appear as a border withing the outer box.. hard to verbalize. the div contains several ul's that I want to maintain a height of 64px, and I want the div to have a set height also. however, the div seems unresponsive to any height I set in css, it just wants to do its own thing I guess and instead has decided that it should base its height on how many ul's there are within it.. I was hoping someone could explain whats going on with it, why it wont obey my commands, and possibly offer a solution.

here's the css:

```
#selectUnitScreen {
overflow: hidden;
min-width:390;
min-height:350;
left:5%;
top:5%;
bottom:5%;
right:5%;
padding:5%;
border-left: solid red 5px;
border-right:solid red 5px;
border-top: solid red 12px;
border-bottom: solid red 12px;
}

#selectUnitScreen ul {
height:64px;
}

#selectUnitScreen li {
font-size:25px;
padding-left: 5%;
display: inline-block;
}

#buildUnitScreen {
padding: 3px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
border-radius: 2%;
border: 3px solid black;
width:400px;
height:470px;
background: white;
box-shadow: 4px 0px 2px 1px black;
left:260px;
top:200px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<section id="buildUnitScreen">

<div id="selectUnitScreen">
    <ul id="build">
        <li class="name">

            infantry

        </li>
        <li class="cost">

            1000

        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="build">
        <li class="name">

            mechenized infantry

        </li>
        <li class="cost">

            3000

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/FJV8b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your not setting units for the `min-height` and `min-width`. You say 390 and 350 but what are those? px? Otherwise those values are ignored. So:

`min-height:350px;`